# NullPointerException in UserRecoverableAuthException.getIntent() in Google Play Services

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play-services

I've noticed strange exception in Google Play Services library:

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.Intent.(Intent.java:3503)
at com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException.android.content.Intent getIntent()(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Do you use google-play-services.jar? And if yes: Which version?

Comment: The newest version 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After examining `google-play-services.jar` I've found that they pass `null` as `Intent` in `UserRecoverableAuthException` constructor...

So a workaround would be:

```
catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableAuthException) {
            Intent intent = userRecoverableAuthException.getIntent();

            if (intent != null) {
                mActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_AUTH_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
```

EDIT:

After playing with java decompiler I've found a reason:

`throw new UserRecoverableAuthException("AppDownloadRequired", null);`
is thrown in `GoogleAuthUtil` class when `bindService` returns false.

Solution for this would be throwing another type of exception or providing valid intent for such kind of situations.

It's a shame that Google do not provide issue tracker for Google Play Services...

UPDATE:

Examining new revision (r13) of source seems that problem was fixed.

Comment: Can you please tell me what scope you were using? Also deviceInfo and the actual code would help us track down the issue.

Comment: Um, checking whether getIntent() returns null doesn't help, as the problem is not that it returns null, but rather that it throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: The getIntent() method is what throws the exception. See the 3rd line of the OP's traceback and the second line of your workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem,

Method `userRecoverableAuthException.getIntent()` related to **Drive** class,
Therefore, I think you need check **Drive** class, that's really necessarily.

Ex : `public static Drive mDriveService;`
*(It is mDriveService)*